# Reorder multidimensional array elements to move subarrays to bottom of element list in all subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Solving one problem created another...
I have got updating array keys based on an map array to work, however it moves the newly mapped keys to the bottom of the array. I need subarrays at the bottom of the elements list.

A truncated snip of the array looks like this after renaming keys:

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'Sink',
    'sublineitems' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'quantity' => 1,
        'model' => 'PBMS2016-12-X',

        'customerspecificpricings' => 
        array (
        ),
        'electricalutilitygrids' => 
        array (
        ),
        'plumbingutilitygrids' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'remarks' => '3-1/2" drain opening',
          ),
        ),
        'subline_item_id' => '844b7c74-b1b7-4f17-a2da-f0c84cef432d',
        'item_type_code' => 0,
        'item_type_description' => 'Normal',
        'vendor_id' => '4e1ab2ef-774e-4c73-be60-c937d1efeb56',
      ),
    ),
    'lineitem_id' => 'e592feab-1e1a-4cfc-a97a-f1108c7156b6',  *** needs to follow 'category' ***
    'item_number' => '1', *** needs to follow 'lineitem_id' ***
  ),
```

The key for the non-numeric subarrays is used as the table name.  When iterating the array, 'sublineitems' subarray is encountered before 'lineitem_id' and 'item_number'.  I need to reorder the elements so that the subarrays fall after the other elements in the array/subarrays.  The arrays are nested 6-8 arrays deep and the key names are not the same for all arrays.

I have tried array_map(array_values), array_multisort, json_encode/decode.  The order is not affected.

The desired outcome is an array that groups non-array elements at the top of each array/subarray.

```
array (
  'category' => 'Mop Sink',
  'lineitem_id' => 'e592feab-1e1a-4cfc-a97a-f1108c7156b6',
  'item_number' => '1',
  'sublineitems' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'quantity' => 1,
      'model' => 'PBMS2016-12-X',
      'cube' => 4.0,
      'width' => 24.63,
      'depth' => 19.38,
      'height' => 16.0,
      'gtin' => 'null|null|null',
      'subline_item_id' => '844b7c74-b1b7-4f17-a2da-f0c84cef432d',
      'item_type_code' => 0,
      'item_type_description' => 'Normal',
    ....
      'customerspecificpricings' => 
      array (
      ),
      'electricalutilitygrids' => 
      array (
      ),
      'plumbingutilitygrids' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'remarks' => '3-1/2" drain opening',
        ),
      ),
      'gassteamutilitygrids' => 
      array (
      ),
      'hvacutilitygrids' => 
      array (
      ),
```

I used a kluge to solve the immediate problem with the lineitems array:

```
        if(isset($value['sublineitems'])){
            $value['sublineitems2'] = $value['sublineitems'];
            unset($value['sublineitems']);
            $value['sublineitems'] = $value['sublineitems2'];
            unset($value['sublineitems2']);
        }
```

but here has to be a better way...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive approach to sort on data types at each level.

My snippet will modify by reference (the array is not "returned" by the function).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kd3RT))

```
function sortByDataTypeRecursive(array &$array)
{
    uasort($array, fn($a, $b) => is_array($a) <=> is_array($b));
    //asort($array); <-- this is slightly different because it implement a more complex sort on values
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            (__FUNCTION__)($v);
        }            
    }
}

sortByDataTypeRecursive($array);
var_export($array);
```

Comment: @mickmakusa - works beautifully!  out of curiosity - it does reorder the outer numerical keys.  Is it possible to retain the numerical order of the outer key without affecting the inner array keys?  I tried array_values to no avail.   thank you!

Comment: @star can you give me an example of what you mean? (via 3v4l demo)  I don't think I understand your requirement.  Do you only want to sort the first level of each entry? https://3v4l.org/DaH5r

Comment: the function does exactly want I wanted.  My question is more about increasing my understanding... The original outer array index is numerical and in ascending order, i.e. [0], [1], [2]...  After the sort, the outer indexes are no longer in numerical ascending order, but [31], [90], [4], etc.  I was curious if there was a way to reorder the array to [0], [1], [2]... after the sort (without any changes to the subarrays).  It works great and the order doesn't affect anything I'm doing, just looking for a deeper understanding.  TY!

Comment: I'm not sure why `array_values()` wouldn't be suitable for that.  Perhaps show me how you've implemented the `array_values()` call so that I can review it.  If, say, you only wanted to preserve the keys of non-indexed arrays (on any level), you can conditionally call `uasort()` and `usort()`. https://3v4l.org/WqCKe

Comment: I believe I figure it out - thank you for your help!! Much appreciated!